# Github Actions | if statement doesn't work

Tags: if-statement, yaml, github-actions

I have a github actions workflow in which I have some steps that are conditional.

This is an example for a step with condition:

```
    - name: Print service name
      if: ${{ github.event.client_payload.service_name }} === 'ServiceTest' || ${{ github.event.client_payload.service_name }} === 'ServiceProd'  
      run: echo ${{ github.event.client_payload.service_name }}
```

How ever, in this case the echo is "ServiceStatGenerator" and yet I go inside this step to perform the "run" and print the name of the server.
How come?

Also tried the condition with 2 equal signs

```
      if: ${{ github.event.client_payload.service_name }} == 'ServiceTest' || ${{ github.event.client_payload.service_name }} == 'ServiceProd'
```

But still it doesn't work as expected.
Please let me know what you think.. I am starting to lose hope here

Answer (score 2):

You have to put == inside the ${{ }}

```
if: ${{ github.event.client_payload.service_name == 'ServiceTest' ||  github.event.client_payload.service_name == 'ServiceProd' }}
```